# How to load another language variables by REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api

How to load the another language storeview variables /text like product name and others in REST API.

I need this type of multi language website for get the api response like below

Arabic - http://www.example.com/index.php/rest/ar/V1/products?fields=items&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=288&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=in&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][field]=status&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][value]=1&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][conditionType]=eq&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=created_at&%20searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=DESC&searchCriteria[pageSize]=10&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1

English - http://www.example.com/index.php/rest/en/V1/products?fields=items&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=288&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=in&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][field]=status&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][value]=1&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][conditionType]=eq&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=created_at&%20searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=DESC&searchCriteria[pageSize]=10&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1

Please anyone tell me to achieve like this.. Thanks in advance